# Trying to automate gmail signup page using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This is how far I have been. But, I am having hard time automating the texts that are in drop-down menu. I tried to automate using select statements, but with no success. I used select while automating facebook signup page and it worked.  Following is the code I used during the process

```
    package signUp;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by san on 4/18/17.
 */
public class LoginCredintials {

    @Test


    public void GoogleSignup(){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/abc/Downloads/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default";
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        //By ID Text area1
        WebElement text1 = driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName"));
        text1.clear();
        text1.sendKeys("San ");

        WebElement text2 = driver.findElement(By.id("LastName"));
        text2.clear();
        text2.sendKeys("P");

        WebElement text3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GmailAddress']"));
        text3.clear();
        text3.sendKeys("s20077");

        WebElement text4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
        text4.clear();
        text4.sendKeys("123abcdxy");

        WebElement text5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PasswdAgain']"));
        text5.clear();
        text5.sendKeys("123abcdxy");

        WebElement text6 = driver.findElement(By.id("BirthDay"));
        text6.clear();
        text6.sendKeys("1");

        WebElement text7 = driver.findElement(By.id("BirthYear"));
        text7.clear();
        text7.sendKeys("2000");

        WebElement text8 = driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryPhoneNumber"));
        text8.clear();
        text8.sendKeys("9222103436");

        WebElement text9 =  driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryEmailAddress"));
        text9.clear();
        text9.sendKeys("abc_gh@yahoo.com");


        Select droplist1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("gender")));
        droplist1.selectByVisibleText("Male");

        Select droplist2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")));
        droplist2.selectByVisibleText("March");

        Select droplist3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CountryCode']/div")));
        droplist3.selectByVisibleText("United States");

        WebElement text10 = driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton"));
        text10.click();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a custom method for selecting values from the required drop-downs, as they are not standard select components. Hence, you need to first click on the dropdown and wait for the options to appear. Once, the options are visible, you can click on the required option. I have written a generic method 'googleSelect' for this purpose below:

```
package signUp;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



/**
* Created by san on 4/18/17.
*/
public class LoginCredintials {

    static WebDriver driver = null;

    @Test
    public void GoogleSignup(){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/abc/Downloads/geckodriver");

   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default";
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    //By ID Text area1
    WebElement text1 = driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName"));
    text1.clear();
    text1.sendKeys("San ");

    WebElement text2 = driver.findElement(By.id("LastName"));
    text2.clear();
    text2.sendKeys("P");

    WebElement text3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GmailAddress']"));
    text3.clear();
    text3.sendKeys("s20077444");

    WebElement text4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
    text4.clear();
    text4.sendKeys("123abcdxy");

    WebElement text5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PasswdAgain']"));
    text5.clear();
    text5.sendKeys("123abcdxy");

    WebElement text6 = driver.findElement(By.id("BirthDay"));
    text6.clear();
    text6.sendKeys("1");

    WebElement text7 = driver.findElement(By.id("BirthYear"));
    text7.clear();
    text7.sendKeys("2000");

    WebElement text8 = driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryPhoneNumber"));
    text8.clear();
    text8.sendKeys("9222103436");

    WebElement text9 =  driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryEmailAddress"));
    text9.clear();
    text9.sendKeys("abc_gh@yahoo.com");


    googleSelect(By.id("Gender"), "Male");

    googleSelect(By.id("BirthMonth"), "March");

    googleSelect(By.xpath(".//*[@id='CountryCode']/div"), "United States");

    WebElement text10 = driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton"));
    text10.click();

    driver.quit();

 }


 private static void googleSelect(By by, String text) {
    driver.findElement(by).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical']//div[text()='" + text + "']"))));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical']//div[text()='" + text + "']")).click();

  }
}
```

Try above code and let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: This code works but how would you know if sign up is successful?

Answer (score 0):

Check the html side of the page. Sometimes check boxes are written as links. So you have to click on the drop down first and click on the element you have to select. I may not be right but if you can please check.

Answer (score 0):

just saw the signup page. looks like it's made up div and li elements so Select won't work. i also saw values being set into hidden fields like "HiddenGender", "HiddenBirthMonth". try developer tools inspect element on chrome to get the fields you require and set the values to these hidden elements directly. Hope this helps.